# Recurrent series from Euler

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am reading Euler's Introduction to analysis of the infinite and get stuck here. I wish to ask two questions:

1) The part I don't understand is circled in red box. If I understand correctly, he is trying expand the binomial series for binomial, trinomial and quadrinomial and finally polynomial expression. But I don't understand how did he derive the recurrent relationship between the first and the second coefficients, the second and the third, and so forth.

I have also numbered the red box for easy reference.

For example, for red box number 2, I don't understand where does $\dfrac{2m-n}{n}\beta\cdot L$ come from?

2) I also don't understand the yellow part. Is this the consequence of expanding a trinomial into trinomial series?

[image]

Comment: This is just a guess. From red box 1, he *conjectured* that $N$ (in red box 2) is of the form $\frac{m-n}{n}\alpha M+(\text{something})\times L$. Calculating $(B-\frac{m-2}{2}\alpha A)/1$, $(C-\frac{m-3}{3}\alpha B)/A$, $(D-\frac{m-4}{4}\alpha C)/B$ and so on, he *conjectured* that the relation in red box 2 holds. This might be how $\frac{2m-n}{n}\beta$ appears.

Answer (score 2):

For the first red box, they're getting an expression for the $(m+1)$th (or $n$th) coefficient (defined as $N$) in terms of the $m$th coefficient (defined as $M$).

Note the last two terms in the equations preceding red box 1 and note that in this case $m=2$ and $n=m+1=3$:

$$M = \alpha^2\frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{1\cdot 2}; N = \alpha^3\frac{(m-1)(m-2)(m-3)}{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3},$$

so

$$N=\alpha \frac{m-3}{3}M.$$

The other red boxes are similar redefinition of coefficients to get recurrence formulas.

For the yellow part, these terms come from multiplying out $(\alpha z + \beta z z)^2$:

$$(\alpha z + \beta z z)^2 = \alpha^2z^2+2\alpha\beta z^3+\beta^2z^4.$$

(Only the first two terms are written out explicitly. The last term is a higher-order term covered by the "etc.")

To verify these formulas, it really is just a matter of multiplying the things out and doing all of the bookkeeping, and looking at the patterns. If you pick a particular value of $m$, this will determine a particular value of $n$, which is the highest power of $z$ in the overall expansion. Then just call the other coefficients $A, B, C,$ and so forth, and you'll find that the relations in the red boxes hold for the particular values of $m$ and $n$.

You can start simply with $m=2$. Then there's nothing even to multiply out and you can verify things immediately.

Then move to $m=3$. This will square the polynomial on the left sides of the equations. In section 75, $n=4$ because your highest power is $z^4$. In section 76, $n=6$ because your highest power is $z^6$.

Then try $m=4$, and if you're not tired yet, try $m=5$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still don't understand the yellow part. You said multiplying out. Could you do in an example so I can learn?

Comment: I edited my answer with some more explanation.

Comment: What about the recurrent formula $B=\dfrac{m-2}{2}\alpha\cdot A+\dfrac{2m-2}{2}\beta$. Where does $\dfrac{2m-2}{2}\beta$ come from? I don't understand where does he get $\dfrac{2m-2}{2}$

Comment: All of these formulas are found by applying the [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series) to the polynomial. This is what gives you the expansion at the start of each section. From there, multiply out the resulting polynomials in the expansion, and combine like powers of $z$ and observe the patterns.

Comment: I know these formulas used the binomial expansion, what I don't understand is $\dfrac{2m-n}{n}$ and $\dfrac{3m-n}{n}$. Where do they come from. To be more useful, can you just write out in more details how the binomial expansion gives rise to these coefficients?

Comment: I added some more explanation. Try a simple case like I outlined in my answer.

Comment: I sort of understand the binomial part now. But I still fail to grasp where does the $B=\dfrac{m-2}{2}\alpha\cdot A+\dfrac{2m-2}{2}\beta$ come from, I don't know where does $\dfrac{2m-n}{n}$ comes from.